# Suggestions to render good looking texts on a browser using opensource libraries

Tags: php, javascript, html

you know when we display texts on pages in the way is ment to, no matter if is whit `<p>` or `<h1>` or any other tag the result is always the same:

[image]
(*a screen capture of a render made on firefox*)

Pixalated areas on the curves of the text. Is any way to render good looking texts on the browser with cross browser capabilities using libraries made on *javascript* or *php*? (*the text must be **selectable***).

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661658/anti-aliased-font-in-html-page

Comment: if you haven't ever tried jquery, check it out.  It may not get you exactly what you want with the text but it is great for cross browser stuff

Comment: You are looking for **anti-aliased** font rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these typeface solutions - all of them allow you to use non standard fonts and produce great looking antialiased output

javascript solutions

- [Cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/)
- [Typeface](http://typeface.neocracy.org/)
- [Google WebFonts](http://code.google.com/webfonts)

flash solutions

- [sifr3](http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr3/)

Comment: i'll suggest to take a look to fontsquirrel too

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using CSS, it's cross browser and can generate really amazing stuff.
Some [examples and tutorials](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/advanced-css-text-effects-web-typography-tips/)  I've found, loads of those to be found via google ;)