# Javascript Text Anti-alias - is it possible without typeface?

Tags: javascript

I need a way to antialias text on a webpage. The normal solutions (flash and/or an image) are out, because:

- we need i(Phone/Pod/Pad) capability (forget flash)
- for unrelated reasons, an image would need to be transparent, and be able to be created on-the-fly using PHP. I've  succeeded at creating a transparent PNG with anti-aliased text in PHP - and it looks hideously awful because PHP wants to create the text on top of a solid-color background and then delete the background.

So it looks like javascript is my best bet, and previous SO questions (for example [Anti-aliased font in HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661658/anti-aliased-font-in-html-page)) have pointed to typeface.js as the option there. But typeface won't convert some of my fonts because they're copyrighted. *Copyrighted or not, I need a solution*. I do have the fonts in all necessary formats to be viewed on the web (eot, svg, ttf, woff) but typeface also wants a separate .js file for each font, and I don't know how to create that manually.

Since typeface.js hasn't been updated in over a year and a half, and the SO question I listed above as an example is 3 years old, I'm hoping there's a more recent solution that may work for me.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If there's a combination of OS and browser that doesn't support such feature (maybe Internet Explorer 4 on Windows 98?), how can JavaScript help?

Comment: that's the question exactly - is there a way to do it with javascript. As it turns out, since I wrote this question I came up with a better way to generate a transparent image with PHP so that's what I'm using now. I'd still prefer a javascript solution if such a thing were possible.

Comment: But you can't turn your page into a giant picture. That's against all usability principles...

Comment: I don't mean the entire page, I mean just a certain section of text. It sounds like you're saying it can't be done, in which case the answer to my question is "no, it can't be done".